# Measuring uniformity of CRC32 by using birthday problem

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to measure what is the probability that given some data and it's CRC32 checksum there is some other data with the same checksum.
Running the simulation is not feasible because of the 2^32 possible values.
Running the simulation for the birthday problem is feasible (check if there is a collision among n checksums)
Is there a way to infer the probability mentioned above by simulating the birthday problem?

Comment: As stated, the problem is trivial: given any string $s$, it is guaranteed that there is some other string with the same checksum as $s$.

Comment: David, that is not true. It is guaranteed that there are two strings that produce a collision, but you can't fix a string and prove that there must be a collision.

Comment: @adrianN You're only using the most basic version of the pigeonhole principle: if more than $n$ things are placed in $n$ groups, at least one group must contain at least two things. However, there's the more advanced version: if more than $kn$ things are placed in $n$ groups, at least one group contains at least $k$ things. But we know even more than that. A good hash function has the property that hash values are well-distributed over the range of 32-bit integers. I'm not sure if there genuinely is a collision for *every* hash value but there will be collisions for the overwhelming majority.

Comment: There are 3 possible questions you could be asking.  (1) What is the "probability" that there exists a CRC32 checksum that has only one message mapping to it (the answer is obviously 0 as shown by DW below), (2) what is the probability that of $N$ messages one of them has CRC32 checksum $X$ (obviously $1-(\frac{2^{32}-1}{2^{32}})^N$ by simple probability) or (3) what is the probability that out of $N$ messages 2 have identical checksums (which is the birthday paradox.)  Which one are you asking?

Comment: If the input data is of limited size, say 64bits and we compute the checksum for each, I think that not all 32bit values will be generated. Some of the 2^32 buckets wont have any associated 64 bit value. This means that given a piece of 64bit data and its 32bit checksum the probability that there it has the same checksum is not 1/2^32, it's 1/number_of_buckets. But it should be more complicated than this

Comment: That's yet a fourth question.  Think of CRC as taking the remainder from a division problem.  If you divide by $D$ then you can get any remainder in the range $0 \ldots D-1$.  And you get each remainder with approximately equal probability.  (Consider taking the remainder of dividing your 64 bit numbers by "15" for example.)  CRC is considering both the message and the divisor as polynomials, and you are doing polynomial long division, but the argument is the same.

Comment: This post and the article it mentions indicate that CRC is not uniform http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575905/hash-functions-with-good-uniformity-for-unknown-input

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with the birthday paradox.

The birthday paradox says, given a collection of $n$ people, what are the chances that some pair of them have the same birthday.

Your question is analogous to the following: given a specific date (say, April 17), and given a collection of $n$ people, what are the chances that one of them has a birthday on that date (on April 17).  That has a very different answer from the birthday question.

As the question was posed, David Richerby has the right answer: due to the properties of the CRC checksum, it is guaranteed that there exists another message that has the same CRC.

If you want to *find* such a message, there are standard techniques using linear algebra (see e.g. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/698/351).

If you want to know, given a 32-bit checksum $c$ and a collection of $n$ messages, what is the probability that at least one of those $n$ messages has checksum $c$, this can be computed too.  That probability is $1-(1-2^{-32})^n \approx 1-e^{-n/2^{32}}$, due to the properties of the CRC (when the message is uniformly distributed, so too is the CRC).

Comment: If a random sample of 23 people have probability p>0.5 that two have the same birthday then the birthdays of the people are not uniform. Similarly by generating ~sqrt(2^32) random pieces of data and calculating their CRC32 and finding out that the probability of having an equal pair is not consistent with the theory then this would indicate a skew in CRC32 distribution. Yes the birthday problem has nothing to do with the problem of finding out the probability to generate a given CRC.

Comment: ... But noticing a difference in the theory while simulating the birthday problem would indicate that the distribution of generating a given CRC is not uniform.

Comment: I don't know how one could calculate the deviation from uniformity for the second problem while having the simulation results from the birthday problem

Comment: I would like to simulate the problem of generating a given CRC and figure out the distribution, unfortunately this is not feasible. I thought that it could be inferred from the distribution given by the birthday problem.

Comment: @titus The birthday problem is precisely about uniform distributions. It deals with questions such as, if I draw $k$ numbers **from the uniform distribution** over $\{1, \dots, n\}$, what is the probability that two of my numbers are the same?

Comment: Indeed. But if the simulation with CRC yields a different results than the theory then it should mean that CRC is not uniform

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are essentially asking "given that I have produced $N$ random 32-bit numbers, what is the probability that all $N$ are unique?"

There are $Q=2^{32}$ ways to choose the first number, $Q-1$ ways to choose the second number, $Q-2$ ways to choose the third number, and so on.  So there are $\frac{Q!}{(Q-N)!}$ ways of choosing $N$ numbers that are unique.  Yet there are a total of $Q^N$ ways of choosing $N$ random numbers from the range $1\ldots Q$, so the probability that all $N$ chosen numbers are unique is
$$
\frac{Q!}{Q^N (Q-N)!}.
$$

You can calculate it exactly with:

$$
\prod_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{Q-k}{Q}.
$$

Or using Stirling's approximation, $n! \approx (\frac{n}{e})^n \sqrt{2 \pi n}$, and the truncated Taylor series, $\ln (1+x) \approx x$, I get the approximation

$$
e^{\frac{N}{Q} (\frac{1}{2} - N)}.
$$

Comment: Note that computing $(2^{32})!$ isn't remotely feasible: $61!$ is already bigger than the number of atoms in the universe. You need to use something like Stirling's approximation to make the computation manageable.

Comment: I actually want to infer the probability that for a given hash value there is another data that hashes to the same hash value. I would like to infer this from how the simulation of birthday problem differs from the theoretical $\frac{Q!}{Q^N (Q-N)!}.$

Comment: @titus: Simulating the birthday problem gives exactly the "theoretical" $\frac{Q!}{Q^N(Q-N)!}$.  If you are _given_ a value $X$ the probability that any subsequent hash gives $X$ is $2^{-32}$ and the probability that _none_ of the next $N$ hashes gives $X$ is $(\frac{2^{32}-1}{2^{32}})^N$.  But that is not the birthday paradox.

Comment: To expand on @WanderingLogic's point, the birthday problem is "Given a set of $n$ people, what is the probability that two of them have the same birthday?" Your question is analogous to, "Given $n$ people, what is the probability that one of them has the same birthday as me?" This is a completely different problem, whose solution has nothing to do with the birthday problem.

Comment: If I simulate by generating N data snippets randomly and applying the CRC32 on them I think is not the same as generating 32bit values randomly, the CRC32 should skew the distribution somehow

Comment: @titus: That would mean that CRC32 is a horrible checksum.

Comment: @titus The whole point of checksums is that they behave a lot like pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: @David This post and mentioned articles indicate that CRC is not uniform (that's why it shouldn't be used for hashing where this is important) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575905/hash-functions-with-good-uniformity-for-unknown-input